# How can there be a linear correlation between two PCA components?

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction

I perform principal component analysis (PCA) on a dataset, and then plot the first and the second principal components. I get the following phenomenon: one principal component appears to be a linear function of the other.

I assume there is no guarantee this would not happen, but I am wondering if there are theorems or known results that may help me understand what causes this phenomenon in my data.

Comment: Thank you! Now it is clear. I would suggest you to edit your question and replace "PCA coefficients" with "principal components", as this is standard terminology. As to your question, such a situation is impossible: correlation between different PCs must be exactly zero. I guess you have a mistake somewhere. Posting your data, output plots, and/or the code you use for analysis might help to catch it.

Comment: Sorry, but, you SEE some correlation (e.g., by plotting the first v/s the second principal component) or you measured it by some way (e.g., computed the correlation coefficient and/or the covariance between the variables)? The covariance HAS to be zero, but that does not imply that you might see some dependance!

Comment: Exactly. The question is: what does a linear correlation of a subset of the data imply on my data?

Answer (score 1):

Do you really see linear correlation in your plot?  If this is the case, you probably didn't do PCA appropriately. The PCA plot should in most cases be symmetrical with respect to PC0 and PC1 axises.

Comment: I use MATLAB's pca function, which I assume does the job correctly. I don't get this phenomenon for any type of data, but in this case - I do.

Comment: Note that I do not get an EXACT linear correlation, there are outliers, but most of the data is linearly correlated after PCA.

Comment: What if you do the PCA plot on data without those outliers?  Extreme outliers can significantly change the variance structure of the data. Otherwise, linear arrangement in general indicates linear dependence, in other words, your data maybe roughly modeled by a single variable.